# Phonegap: Can you create 2 writers for a single file?

Tags: android, file, cordova, writer

I've recently started using phonegap to develop on android. I ran into this problem while learning the File plugin API, I was wondering if it is possible to create 2 writers for a file (on two different pages). When I tried the code below on two different pages (one writes: "This team has not been scouted" and the other writes: "This team has been scouted :)" For some reason only one will work at a time, if i run the first one first it creates the file and writes to it, but the second one won't work. Likewise, if I run the second one first it creates the file and writes to it, but the first one won't work.

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
alert("waiting...");
// Wait for device API libraries to load
//
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// device APIs are available
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    alert("Device Ready!");
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onRequestFileSystemSuccess, null);
}
function onRequestFileSystemSuccess(fileSystem) {
    alert("Got file system!");
    fileSystem.root.getDirectory("FRC_SCOUT_DATA", { create: true }, onGotDir, null);

}
function onGotDir(dataDir) {
    alert("Got Directoy!");
    dataDir.getFile("data_1539.txt", { create: true, exclusive: true }, onFileCreated, null);
    alert("Got File!");
}
function onFileCreated(dataFile) {
    dataFile.createWriter(gotFileWriter, null);
}
function gotFileWriter(writer) {
    writer.write("This team has been scouted :)"); 
}


</script>
```

(code on second page is essentially the same with the exception of the message thats being written to the text file)

Comment: whats de error u get in second page ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have kept `exclusive: true` .So it will give you an error if file already exist try setting it to false.Check this [out](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#Flags)

So change your code from this

```
dataDir.getFile("data_1539.txt", { create: true, exclusive: true }, onFileCreated, null);
```

to

```
dataDir.getFile("data_1539.txt", { create: true, exclusive: false}, onFileCreated, fail);

function fail(error) {
    console.log(error.code);
}
```

Comment: Ah i should have seen that in the documentation, did the trick though thanks!